# List of github users being followed by me

Tags: github

When you follow someone on GitHub, you'll get notifications on your dashboard about their activity. But where will I get the list of the people I am following?

Comment: as of March '24: from your profile page, click the 'following' link below your avatar image on the left of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GitHub public REST API for getting the following users list as a JSON object.
`https://api.github.com/users/{username}/following`

Answer (score 2):

The links to Followers / Starred and Following are just below the user pic on homepage!

Will not find it in "settings".

Answer (score 1):

Here is the direct link: https://github.com/shantanuo/following

In general: github.com/{{username}}/following

Answer (score 1):

As of April 2023, the **"Following"** link can be found on your profile page, **`https://github.com/[username]`**, at the left side below the edit profile button:

[image: Your profile page left side with an arrow pointing to 'Following' link]

You can also link to it directly by adding **`?tab=following`** to the end of the profile page URL:
**`https://github.com/[username]?tab=following`**